# Select from table where field data 'like' variable

Tags: php, laravel

The script works just fine, but not as expected.

```
$table = $_POST['table'];
$field = $_POST['field'];
$condition = $_POST['condition'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

if ($condition == 'Contains') { $newcondition = 'like'; }

$builder = DB::table($table)->where($field, $newcondition, '%'.$value.'%')->get();
```

For example, my field data looks like this: **A, B, C, D**

It gives me correct results, if `$value` is in same order: **A, B** (if value is in original order).

But it does not give results at all, if `$value` is **A, D** or in different order.

How to make this script to work, if `$value` is not in original order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the `$value` and create a custom `whereRaw` with `AND` for each individual value. I would also suggest that you examine whether or not it makes sense to be storing your data the way you have it saved, especially if the query you are making now is one you plan to make often. There might be much more efficient ways to store it.

```
$values = explode(', ', $value);
$query = "";
foreach($values as $param) {
    $query .= $field.' LIKE %'.$param.' AND' 
}
$query = rtrim($query, " AND");
```

Comment: Good idea, i was thinking about that, but maybe there is more "simple" way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a simpler way, mainly because you are storing multiple values in one attribute.

Comment: Looks like your script is correct, but i need to spend more time to investigate this. I was thinking the same way. But.. i know this is not correct way to store a data, but this was what owners wanted, in "old way".

Comment: Glad I could help!